# How to structure a TypeScript interface that types a value based upon an object of interfaces

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a TypeScript interface that correctly types the key and property based on an object of models.

```js
interface ModelA {
  label: string
}
interface ModelB {
  name: string
}

interface Models {
  A: ModelA
  B: ModelB
}

interface Command<Model extends keyof Models> {
  table: Model
  attribute: keyof Models[Model]
}
```

The above example almost works, but `Command` requires a type provided, which renders it non-functional.

```js
const commands: Command<any>[] = [
  // because I need to pass a type argument, it breaks things, there is no typing here
  { table: 'A', attribute: 'label' },
  { table: 'B', attribute: 'name' },
]
```

If I change `Command` to:

```js
interface Command<Model = keyof Models> {
  table: Model
  attribute: keyof Models[Model]
}
```

Then `Command` doesn't require a type argument, and it correctly types the `table` property to either `A` or `B`; but the `attribute` is invalid, I get an error of:

```
Type 'Model' cannot be used to index type 'Models'
```

Want to have an interface that allows you to create an array of commands, like:

```js
const commands: Command<any>[] = [
  { table: 'A', attribute: 'label' },
  { table: 'B', attribute: 'name' },
]
```

Where the `table` is correctly typed to a key from `Models` and `attribute` is keyed to the model's actual interface.

Comment: If you really want `Command` to be generic but deal with unions this way, then you might want to make it a *distributive object type* as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NrjylN).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Your example does solve for this, I hadn't considered creating an object as a wrapper to create a variable like you do to create `P`. That worked exactly as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that you really want `Command<"A" | "B">` to evaluate to `Command<"A"> | Command<"B">` so that each member of the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in the input `"A" | "B"` corresponds to its own member of the union type in the output, instead of being all mixed together in a single object type.  Put another way: you want `Command<K>` to be *distributive* over unions in `K`.

There are a few approaches to turning a generic type into a distributive version.

---

For arbitrary types you can write a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), wrapping `type F<T> = ⋯` in the seemingly useless `type F<T> = T extends unknown ? ⋯ : never`:

```
type Command<K extends keyof Models = keyof Models> = K extends unknown ? {
  table: K
  attribute: keyof Models[K]
} : never;

type C = Command<keyof Models>;
/* type C = {
    table: "A";
    attribute: "label";
} | {
    table: "B";
    attribute: "name";
} */
```

That works, but the compiler isn't very good at *analyzing* conditional types, so I would avoid them where unnecessary.

---

In the case where your generic type parameter is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints)  to a union of keylike [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), such as `"A" | "B"`, you can instead write a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  It's where you [map over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) each key to make an object and then [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it to get the union out.  You are wrapping `type F<K> = ⋯` in `type F<K> = {[P in K]: F<P>}[K]`:

```
type Command<K extends keyof Models = keyof Models> =
  { [P in K]: {
    table: P
    attribute: keyof Models[P]
  } }[K]

type C = Command<keyof Models>;
/* type C = {
    table: "A";
    attribute: "label";
} | {
    table: "B";
    attribute: "name";
} */
```

---

Both methods produce the same output, where `Command<"A" | "B">` is equivalent to `Command<"A" | "B">`. Often in cases like this it's convenient to give your generic type a [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) so that the bare `Command` is equivalent to `Command<"A" | "B">`.  So I've done that above (instead of `type Command<K extends keyof Models> = ⋯` I wrote `type Command<K extends keyof Models = keyof Models> = ⋯`).

And so that gives you the following behavior, as desired:

```
const commands: Command[] = [
  { table: 'A', attribute: 'label' }, // okay
  { table: 'B', attribute: 'name' }, // okay
  { table: "A", attribute: "name" } // error!
];
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmEA2BBZAbwChlkc4AjXALmQGcwpQBzYgX2NElkRQ2w4AQkVLIQcALYQ6jZiDacu4aPCRosueqLJ46A3HjFD9m4R2ITp9AA59kAYXQhMwMMGdwcosWACeNihOkpJwLgA8ANLIEAAekC7aANYQfugwGoLaALzIKWkZBjj0AHzIudFxCZjaAK4gSSDoAO4gyAD8OmTIYFQ4MsiRYmRwYEzAlLWQdPnpmVoA2pEAumLsyHQgEABu0ADcxL4BQeWO6CFhmAdkAPQAVD3Hjqck3d29lP10AER439dvZCjcaTabIb4Uag4f5rZAAHy6bw+X3BQhhgKBY2YoIG3ysEHRyHWdxuhzICGcjGQFIuiTowVCLgWy1OC2GRB6fQGAHI8NyADSYkFTHmQ3DcomCm43ZDoJJwPzswicz48oQCoXYkV0bn4iXsKUyuUKpUqlG-b6C4FasF4qQEonIaUxKBQdBQACEYlWFks9ts9gAGj4yP5AmdaZgojF4hBEnlUnMijkEwV5sUytlTQsAArIUCDZZ0V6A5EDHPskZYiba1NJsz0XOrN7rdhLH2hp4OU4My4A+6PcPd3IlpFcn5-AFva0121i6EA9YI0fvceownT6s4n74wnE0liCkgKk0xk1ennM-M1mmss6vlWre17nz-WG2XyxVvZV35Dc9WPsKYK6vab5Okan63muFqATauK7o6zrQG6nrehwQA)